Can't access files after changing their permissions
Today is my first time using terminal to turn off some permissions.
This morning when working. I wanted to see the php_error_log while developing. So I opened the file and whenever I have a PHP syntax error the error is sent to that file.
But because I wanted to so see the current error that has been logged in the file I had to always enter an admin password for that file ( php_error_log).
So I run this in the terminal on the XAMPP folder:
sudo chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP

I was happy because this time I do not have to always enter the password when I wanted to open the php_error_log file.
But after that, I had this problem:
the phpmyAdin was saying: phpMyAdmin-error - wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writeable.
I searched online and ran some code on the terminal. Now even localhost says FORBIDDEN!
Now, even the photos.app on my Macbook don't open and it says: You do not have permission to open the application.
The htdocs folder with all my project folders is empty and I can't see anything there.
I can't access the project folders in the htdocs and neither can I get all the databases in the MySQL database.

Your permissions are too wide open as the error message states. Not familiar with xampp, but can u set its permissions to 755 ?

"I searched online and ran some code on the terminal." - ah, yes, that of course tells us everything we need to know ...

"Now, even the photos.app on my Macbook don't open" - how is that related to PHP or Apache?

now the files and folders in the htdocs is back!
and now i'm not forbidden for opening localhost.
but i still have problem with the phpmyAdmin config..
now it says : phpMyAdmin - Error
Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!

i run this: sudo chmod 755 /Applications/XAMPP

"should not be world writable!" - anything unclear about that message?

How do i solve the second problem? should i run the 755 on config file?

As the error suggests, you should not have files 777 (world writable).
Having files world writable is a huge security issue.
The maximum permissions you should ever use are 644 for files and 755 for folders.

I get it . i run the 755 on the XAMPP folder and only the files in the htdocs came up this time. but was having problems with phpmyAdmin(mysql). so tried installing the XAMPP with the latest version.
now the mysql started and phpmyadmin worked but colums in the table is lost or corrupted!
i have this error when i click on any table in my database.
#1932 - Table 'crypto.smaq_users' doesn't exist in engine

The database seems to have been corrupted somehow, perhaps when you upgraded XAMPP - did you just copy the mysql data files from the old database to the new? this might not work depending on the MySQL server version differences.
